# oracle apex using dynamic action on a date field

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex, client-side, apex-code

I am a fresher in oracle apex, need some inputs.

There is a form to enter header information. In that there is a date field :P100_ENTERED_DATE, if this field value is less than current date then we need to enable another field :P_100_REASON and make it mandatory.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

I tried to do with JS expression to put in the client side condition like below but did not work.

WHEN:
Event: Change
Type: Item
Item(s): :P100_ENTERED_DATE

Client-side Condition: Javascript Expression.

### JS Expression:

```
var ld_cust_date = apex.item("P102_CUST_REQUEST_DATE").getValue();
var current_date = new Date();

if ((current_date - ld_cust_date) > 2){
    return true
  }  
else {
    return false
}
```

True Condition: Enable the field (I also want to make it mandatory, not sure how to do this)
False Conditoin: Disable the field.

Answer (score 1):

This might be one option:

- there are 4 items on a page:

  - P100_SYSDATE

    - hidden
    - source is function body: `return to_char(sysdate, 'dd.mm.yyyy');`
  - P100_ENTERED_DATE

    - date picker
    - format mask: `dd.mm.yyyy`
  - P100_DATE_DIFF

    - hidden
    - it will contain difference between sysdate and entered date
  - P100_REASON

    - text item

Create dynamic action on P100_ENTERED_DATE which fires on Change event and contains 4 true actions:

- hide reason on initialization

  - action: hide
  - affected element: P100_REASON
  - fire on initialization
  - client side condition: item is null, P100_REASON
- set date diff

  - action: set value
  - PL/SQL expression: `to_date(:P100_SYSDATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - to_date(:P100_ENTERED_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy')`
  - items to submit: P100_SYSDATE, P100_ENTERED_DATE
- show reason:

  - action: show
  - affected element: P100_REASON
  - client side condition: item > value; P100_DATE_DIFF; 0
- hide reason

  - action: hide
  - affected element: P100_REASON
  - client side condition: item <= value; P100_DATE_DIFF; 0

Create validation on P100_REASON:

- type is function body, returning error text

  ```
  if :P100_DATE_DIFF > 0 and :P100_REASON is null then
     return ('Reason is required');
  end if;
  ```

That's it. Here are a few testing screenshots (today = SYSDATE = 04.07.2023, 4th of July 2023)

- A: entered date is 02.07.2023 so "reason" has to be displayed and has to contain some value. Submit button raised an error as "reason" is empty
- B: once I entered reason, page was successfully submitted
- C: date (06.07.2023) is after *today* so "reason" shouldn't be displayed and isn't required. Submit ... well, submits the page

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for spending time on this.. I will give a try and let you know if it works.